# Playing Leviathan games for Warhammer 40K when the rules are no longer sold or available for download

Tags: warhammer-40k

Rookie question for Warhammer 40K 10th Edition rules.

It sounds like all official 10th edition Games Workshop tournaments are using the *Leviathan* game format for tournament play, is that correct? If so, the **Leviathan Tournament Companion** (available as a free download off the Community site) states that you have to select your mission from the "*Leviathan Mission Pack*" and it indicates there are 15 so-called Leviathan Missions in this. Unfortunately the Leviathan Tournament Companion doesn't mention what these 15 missions are.

I searched the Games Workshop website and found a *Leviathan Mission Deck* which looks like its those 15 missions (keep me honest!) but it's sold out online. So I ask: how does one obtain the 15 (???) missions of the Leviathan Mission Deck, so they can prepare for Leviathan Tournament play, if they are all [sold out](https://www.warhammer.com/en-US/shop/chapter-approved-leviathan-mission-deck-2023-eng?queryID=77a9220fc209e46d27ea13a5d66838a6)?

Comment: Do you see availability at [the well known retailer named after a river](https://www.amazon.com/Games-Workshop-Warhammer-Approved-Leviathan/dp/B0C8JH7HTS/)? That shows as available for me (as does the GW site for shipping to the UK, but I appreciate that's not particularly helpful for you)

Comment: Yeah @Philip Kendall there's 14 left in stock -- doesn't that strike you as alarming?! What am I missing here?! Isn't WH40K like **huge**? With gazillions of followers/players...

Comment: _shrug_, lots of Amazon is just a storefront for other sellers these days. In that case, it's "MTGbiz" who have 14 copies. While GW's supply to the US has always been a bit hit-and-miss, I'm sure either you or your FLGS can obtain a copy.

Answer (score 3):

The mission pack is still available from multiple retailers, it's just that the Games Workshop US website has no stock as of March 2024. For example, the [Games Workshop UK site](https://www.warhammer.com/en-GB/shop/chapter-approved-leviathan-mission-deck-2023-eng) does have stock, as do multiple third party retailers both in the UK and the US. If you have an FLGS, ask them if they can get you a copy.

That all said, there's a very well known website in the 40k community which  contains all the 40k rules, including the Leviathan mission pack. I'm not going to link it here because it is a copyright violation, but a little bit of searching with your favourite search engine will find it for you.